# MS Access 2003 - Listbox formatting control

Tags: forms, ms-access, listbox, vba

Just some general formatting questions about return records to a list box on a form:

I have a list box that returns sets of records based on SQL statement in VB. I need the SQl statement to return the ID (auto number) of each record, because if the user selects from this list box, I need the ID as a pass parameter to the next form. But I do not need the ID to show up in the actual list....anyway i can hide this, or just not display it?

I used rowsource like this:

```
me.searchlist.rowsource = "SELECT TblMain.MainID, TblMain.First, TblMain.MiddleTblMain.Last FROM TblMain ORDER BY TblMain.Last, TblMain.First DESC;"
```

Also the listbox has no headers, which i want, and has three columns for above example...but each column is way too big, can i control the width size of each column area inside the listbox? I tried the properties window, but that only seems to effect the first column and not all of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- For the Header, the Listbox has a
  property called *Column Heads*
  (default no). Set this to Yes.
- For the column widths, the Listbox
  has a property for *Column Count* and
  *Column Widths*. In your case you can set *Column Count* to 3 and *Column
  Widths* to something like 0;2;3

Comment: That might not be what you were looking for but that's the recommnded and only solution.

Comment: @Justin: just curious why you don't like the answer. It's the way Access is built. If you're bringing expectations from a different programming environment that's *your* problem, don't you think?